# Minimum capacity cut reduction from digraph with two edge weight sets

Tags: graphs, optimization, combinatorics, network-flow

Given a digraph $G$ and $f, g : E(G) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, how would you find a cut $(X,\bar{X})$ with $s \in X$ and $t \in \bar{X}$ such that $\sum_{e \in \delta^+(X)}{f(e)} - \sum_{e \in \delta^-(X)}{g(e)}$ is minimized?

$\delta^+(X)$ is the set of edges going out of $X$ and $\delta^-(X)$ is the set of edges going into $X$.

I can solve for the case where $f = g$, simply by constructing a network flow graph with all edges adjacent to either $s$ or $t$. Since $\sum_{e \in \delta^+(X)}{f(e)} - \sum_{e \in \delta^-(X)}{f(e)}$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{e \in \delta^+(X)}{f(e)} + \sum_{e \notin \delta^-(X)}{f(e)} + constant$ then a graph can be constructed with an edge between $s$ and all $v \notin \{s,t\}$ with capacity equal to $\sum_{e \in \delta^-(v)}{f(e)}$  and an edge between all $v \notin \{s,t\}$ and $t$ with capacity equal to $\sum_{e \in \delta^+(v)}{f(e)}$. Then dealing with negative $f$ is simply a matter of adding the capacity to the $(v,t)$ edge instead of the $(s,v)$ edge and vice versa.

However this solution does not work when $f \neq g$ and I can't come up with an answer for this case.

The solution works for the case that $f=g$ because if we have an edge $(a,b)$, in the case that $a \in X, b \in \bar{X}$ then the edge is going out of X and not going into X, the contribution to the cut capacity is $2f((a,b))$ as per the formula containing the constant above. Then if you add $b$ to $X$, $a$ no longer contributes to the sum over edges going out of $X$ and so $f((a,b))$ is removed and you are left with $f((a,b))$. If $f \neq g$, then you are instead left with $f((a,b)) − g((a,b))$ which is incorrect.

In terms of what I have tried so far for the general case, the case that $g(x) < 0$ is trivial and the edge can simply be reversed and the capacity multiplied by $-1$ so that it is positive.

In the case that both $f,g > 0$ then I consider this local portion of the graph:
[image]

Let $f = f(a,b)$ and $g = g(a,b)$ in the above graph.
I can then transform it to this network graph:
[image]

Where the capacities are given by

- $(s,b) = f$
- $(b,a) = f - g$
- $(a,t) = f$

Clearly this is only applicable in the case where $f > g$. Then in the case that $a$ but not $b$ is added to $X$ we have a net increase of $f$. When $b$ but not $a$ is added to $X$ we have a net decrease of $g$. When both $a$ and $b$ are added to $X$ there is no net change.

However I cannot reconcile this with the case where $f < g$ or $f < 0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. In particular, why does this fail at $f\neq g$  and why can't you come up with an example that fixes it?

Comment: It is better if you edit your question with the clarifications given in the comments. This way, future visitors can immediately understand you without having to look at the comments. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your solution for the case $f=g$.  I'm not seeing why it would work correctly.  In particular, $\delta^+(X) \ne \cup_{v \in X} \delta^+(v)$, so I don't understand why the solution on your constructed graph would be the optimal solution on the original $G$.

Comment: I've edited my question with additional clarification.

My solution should work for the case that $f = g$ because any edge for which both of its vertices is contained in $X$ is effectively cancelled out (because $f = g$).

Sorry if I am not explaining myself very well, I have actually spent hours staring at this question and it is quite late at night for me now.

Comment: Since $f$ can be negative, how do you solve the minimum cut problem on your new graph? In addition, what are $c$ and $c'$?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, if $f$ is negative then multiply it by $-1$ and then add it to the opposite side, i.e. if the edge is going out of $v$ then add $-f$ to $(s,v)$ instead of $(v,t)$. This has the effect of a net decrease of $f$ when $v$ is added to $X$.

Comment: Also, I just realised I changed my variables halfway through from $f,g$ to $c,c'$. I've edited my question to correct this. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard.

Consider the $f=0$ case, then you are trying to minimize $-\Sigma_{e\in\delta^-(X)}g(e)$, i.e. maximize $\Sigma_{e\in\delta^-(X)}g(e)$. This is exactly the [maximum cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut), which is NP-hard.

Comment: I was considering that but my question is exactly one of the exercises in this book: https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Optimization-Theory-Algorithms-Combinatorics/dp/3642244874 ...and it specifically asks to reduce to the minimum capacity cut problem. Is the exercise just misspecified?

Comment: @rojmor I don't know. I know nothing about that book.

Comment: I can't help but laugh that I've wasted several hours trying to come up with a solution to a question that has no solution. Heh. Thanks for your help, now I can sleep.